# ros2 lifecycle state transition topics

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a rclpy node and an associated *launch.py file.

I use ros2 launch "package" "launch file" to launch the node, and I see it successfully start.  Embedding prints in the code seem to indicate that the node is taking lifecycle state transitions.  However, I cannot query the lifecycle state.

I modeled my launch file after the Stereolabs zed node launch file.  Is there an all-python managed node example that uses controlled state transitions for reference?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328772/ros2-lifecycle-state-transition-topics/) by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 553 on 2019-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have created a rclpy node and an associated *launch.py file. [..] Is there an all-python managed node example that uses controlled state transitions for reference?

Unless something has changed recently, managed nodes are currently a C++-only feature.

The [ROS 2 Features](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Features/) page seems to confirm that, as as well as check of the [ros2/rclpy](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy) repository.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1